# Trying to develop a Android anti-virus

Tags: android, virus, malware

i am trying to develop a Android anti-virus and i'm trying to find out what are the possible ways to do it.

So far i found out one of the only ways is to use **PackageManager** and get the list of installed applications with their package names and compare it to a blacklist. Is there a better way of going around this?

Comment: I'd suggest doing some background in how anti-viruses work and common methods of infection and how those infections work. Looking only for packages that are known to be malware will mean you only get a tiny number of hits compared to actual infections

Comment: There is a related question on [IT Security site](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32285/how-do-anti-virus-apps-for-android-work).

Answer (score 6):

Develop a process that runs as root, or even better: a Linux kernel module that audits processes and filesystem files.

The problem with implementing an anti-virus as an entirely userland construct is that malware usually runs at a higher privilege and so can easily evade detection, this is why rootkit infections are so difficult to deal with ("Nuke it from orbit, it's the only way to be sure").

Your next problem is then maintaining a database of virii. Original AV systems back in the 1990s kept databases of hashes of known malwares. The problem is they don't defend against polymorphic executables, those that spread by attaching themselves to other programs, or things like Word macros. The alternative is to develop a Heuristics-based system. You might get away with this in VM-based systems where a program's behavior can be easily analysed (such as locating calls to system functions of use to malware) but a good virus is going to be written in a "native" language, making detection very hard if not impossible (back when I used Norton Anti-virus, their "Bloodhound" heuristics system never worked and always generated too many false-positives).

Finally, you have the mammoth task of researching and maintaining such a database. This is why only large security firms (Symantic, McAfee, NOD, Microsoft, etc) develop AV programs.

If I were you I'd give up right now before you waste any time. If this is an educational exercise then you'll learn more about malware by writing your own virus, rather than writing a system that attempts to stop them.